# Analyze and Partition command in PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I have a SQL query:

```
ANALYSE TABLE CUST_STAT COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

it works well in Oracle, but recently I am switching to use PostgreSQL, I change the SQL to:

```
ANALYSE CUST_STAT COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

I already read the manual section on partitioning, I know the TABLE keywords is not needed in PostgreSQL, but I still getting error for the PARTITION :

```
ANALYZE CUST_STAT  PARTITION CUST_STAT_P201307 ;
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Apparently you are trying to run Oracle SQL statements on a Postgres server. Where did you find that syntax? It's not valid for Postgres

Comment: I don't know how to convert the PARTITION part to postgreSQL

Answer (score 2):

There is no `COMPUTE STATISTICS` sub-command for `ANALYZE` in PostgreSQL.

```
ANALYZE tablename;
```

per [the manual on `ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-analyze.html).

There is also no `PARTITION` keyword. PostgreSQL's partitioning is limited and largely manual. See [the user manual section on partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html).

The PostgreSQL manual is quite detailed and pretty good. I suggest reading it rather than trying to apply Oracle experience directly to Pg. They're not the same DB.

On partitioning, [this tutorial](http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/tutorials-quickstarts/all-platforms/how-partition-table-postgres-plus) is a bit old and is targeted at EnterpriseDB, but I think it uses only standard features, and it might help introduce the concepts. I haven't reviewed it in detail.

Another simple step-by-step example is [on this blog entry](http://www.mkyong.com/database/partition-table-in-postgresql-create-partition-part-1/).

Examples are no substitute for *understanding* though, and this is an area you *need* to understand, not just follow recipes for. If you don't have time for that I strongly recommend seeking someone who does to help you with your implementation in-depth.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replied, I check the PostgreSQL Partitioning already, I couldn't understand as it mention need to create a master table without check constriants and data, I am stuck at the Partitioning part.

Comment: @HannSzeEnn In that case it might be an idea to get a bit more experience with the database first. Partitioning is - sadly - not as easy on PostgreSQL.

Comment: This is part of my job, so I have to figure out anyway thanks.

Comment: @HannSzeEnn Well, this tutorial is a bit old and is targeted at EnterpriseDB, but I think it uses only standard features, and it might help introduce the concepts. http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/tutorials-quickstarts/all-platforms/how-partition-table-postgres-plus . Another simple step-by-step example is http://www.mkyong.com/database/partition-table-in-postgresql-create-partition-part-1/ . Examples are no substitute for *understanding* though, and this is an area you need to *understand*.

Comment: @HannSzeEnn BTW, please mention things like "I already read the manual section on partitioning but ..." and *your PostgreSQL version* in questions.